# How do I load the content inside div after every 5 seconds?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, widget

I have been trying to load a particular div element after every 5 seconds with some stock quotes which I received using a stock widget from http://webthegap.com/widgets/stock-market/
This widget is static and only refreshes when I refresh the page. So far my jquery code is :-

```
setInterval("my_function();",5000); 
    function my_function(){
      $('#refresh').load(location.href + '#time');
    }
```

And HTML ids in which stock widget is placed is

```
<div id="refresh" class="stock-section">
    <div id="time" class="container">
</div>
</div>
```

The problem is, the page does refreshes but the data inside the widget disappears as you can see in the screenshot below :-

[image: Before refresh Image]

[image: After refresh Image]

Is there any way to fix this??

Comment: `setInterval()` takes a callback and a time in milliseconds... at the minute, you're passing it a string and a time?

Comment: What happens after the next five e seconds?

Comment: After the next five seconds, it remains empty.

Comment: So basically, it loads and disappears. Is that it?

Comment: I would perhaps look in to using sockets for this. 5 seconds between polls is very short, and may be demanding on your server depending on the processing being done and the number of concurrent visitors.

Comment: In your code above, nothing should happen after 5 seconds: your setInterval would try to run a string and fail, and your myfunction() would never be called.

Answer (score 0):

Your `setInterval` is trying to call a string and not a function. In the first parameter you have to pass the function name (note below it does not have the parenthesis) and the second is, as you have it, a number in milliseconds.

It should be like this:

```
setInterval(my_function, 5000);
function my_function(){
  $('#refresh').load(location.href + '#time');
}
```